# Python dictionary iterating over nested dictionaries for a particular operation/function

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a function which has to be executed for the nested dictionaries inside a dictionary. Then how should I execute it ?

For example:

```
# I have the below dictionary
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': {'e':4, 'f':5}}

# I wanted a result as below
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}

#I have executed it by 

for i, j in d.items():

    if type(j) == dict:
        for key,value in d[i].items():
            d[key] = value
        d.pop(i, None)

print d

#output
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}
```

But what if there are many nested dictionaries? I am kind of confused on this ? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recursive call?

Comment: @bharadhwaj yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that this be a form of flattening:

```
def flatten(d):
    es = [d.pop(k) for k in sorted(d) if isinstance(d[k], dict)]
    # Due to sorted the dictionaries those keys that are lexicographically after 
    # will overwrite the key-value pairs from those that are before.

    # One would expect that `d.update(*es)` would work 
    # but it doesn't as `update` only takes one argument.
    for e in es:
        d.update(e)

def flatten_many(d):
    while any(isinstance(d[k], dict) for k in d):
        flatten(d)
```

The first function pops every dictionary from `d` and then updates `d` with them. The second function applies `flatten` the first function while there is a value that is a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks .. It kind a gave me the insight of a recursive function to nested dictionaries. I ll practice more. :)

Comment: Nothing in Dan D.'s answer is recursive (self-calling). Everything is iterative, since flatten() gets called in a while-loop from flatten_many().

Comment: @ChristianKönig But I thought pop function is getting executed recursively here. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: *Repetition* is different from *recursion*. Please have a look at e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
dd={}
def myprint(d):
     for k, v in d.iteritems():
         if isinstance(v, dict):
             myprint(v)
         else:
             dd.update({k:v})
     return dd


d={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': {'e':4, 'f':5,'g':{'h':6}}}
print(myprint(d))
```

output-
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'h': 6}